# Can you transfer items between servers in Rust?

Tags: rust

My friends and myself started playing Rust yesterday and to learn the basics we joined a server with 18 ping and 0/50 players. We build a nice base, looted some villages, killed some mutants and that it. We haven't encountered any other players so things got pretty boring after that. Our/my question would be if you decide to switch to a different server, what items do you keep? Do you keep everything you have on you, do you only keep your research/blueprints or do you lose everything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible to move the items to a different server.

Comment: So, its like a entirely new character when you start a new server?

Comment: Not only "like" but literally a new character.